# JDBC Properties - all or nothing

Tags: jdbc

Can you please help me understand if JDBC offers a property wherein the connection between two database systems is established and if in case JDBC has an inherent property wherein it would transfer all the records from one database to another or transfer nothing (in case the connection is interrupted/fails)?

Comment: Sounds like you're describing a [transaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)).

Comment: Please describe in more detail what you want to do, but on first glance, this doesn't sound like something in JDBC, though maybe something that could exist in a specific JDBC driver for a specific database system.